# Android - How to get Values by Key using FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This code get the values by key and set them in listview.

```
    mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("1234");

    FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
            this,
            String.class,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            mFirebaseDatabase
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {

            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setText(model);


        }
    };
```

Here is the error message :

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String.....

[My firebase:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA1MB.png)

Comment: can you show model class.

Comment: i dont have any model class

Comment: then what is String model.

Comment: then you have to create model class containing getter and setter method.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you get Values by key:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("1234").orderByKey();

FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
        this,
        String.class,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        query
)
```

But in your case the error you are getting is because you have 2 childs in the child("1234") and you're trying to get them as one String which is not the right way, for this follow deepmala's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how to use a FirebaseListAdapter (also not too sure if this is what you're trying to do), but you could always use a SingleValueEventListener.

```
mFirebaseDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String result = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }
        textView.setText(result);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.ListView, strings.toArray(new String[list.size()]));
        ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview)).setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

If you're still having issues, there might be an issue in your database structure or you lack read permissions.

Comment: I want to show data in my listview so im using FirebaseListAdapter

my firebase structure is like this:

{
  "1234" : {
    "-Kha5Xy1J9DEJTRYQoqg" : {
      "phoneNumber" : "97182924",
      "timestamp" : "1492066643"
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I am talking about this file:

```
      public class Model{
        public String phoneNumber;
        public String timestamp;
    public Model() {
            // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Model.class)
        }
        public Model(String phoneNumber, String timestamp) {
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
            }
    //Getters and setters
        public String getphoneNumber() {
                return phoneNumber;
            }
        public void settimestamp(String timestamp) {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }
        public void setphoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        }
      public String gettimestamp() {
            return timestamp;
        }
       @Exclude
        public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
            HashMap<String, Object> result1 = new HashMap<>();
            result1.put("timestamp", timestamp);
            result1.put("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);

            return result1;
        }
}
```